# How to get a straight line on plastic guttering

Tags: gutters

We live in a climate (Utah) which can move from 0F to over 100F during the year.

Our plastic gutters bulge away from the soffit, and it bulges itself; it also leaks at some joints. My long-term plan is to replace with Aluminum, but is there anything I can do in the short term to make these gutters straighter and more waterproof? More ties, or something different? I can't find this profile of gutter in the local hardware stores.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gutter is as wavy as it is partly because not enough hangers were used initially. Vinyl requires more support than steel. Now that it's warped you'll have a hard time straightening it effectively. It's also wavy simply because it's vinyl, which is soft.

Add more hangers and replace the worst sections. Consider replacing it all with steel if you want a truly straight gutter.

Comment: Thanks! Just one more thing the previous owner didn't do correctly...

Comment: After consideration, I went outside with a tape measure, and found that it's only 50ft of vinyl, and everywhere else is aluminum. For not much money, I can change to steel. That's my weekend project planned! Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe I've ever encountered aluminum gutter. Folks also mention aluminum siding often, though both are steel 99% of the time.

Comment: Sorry - meant Steel!